# How to install android build support for unity manually (unity hub)?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I used Unity Hub downloaded latest Unity Editor, it works fine for editor,document and language packs, but can not download android build support. Just told me download failed many many times in the past two days.

So I downloaded `UnitySetup-Android-Support-for-Editor-2018.2.16f1.pkg` from webpage.  This package install reported failed at the end of every try.This package size(348.9M) is not same as the one showed(365.8M) in UnityHub download list.

There is a 2017 version Unity Editor installed by download  **.pkg, but the support installer never ask me about Editor's location.

Is there some way to install android build support manually?
Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the [Android Sdk Manager](https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads) under Command line tools only.
And download the SDK you need, then link it to Unity.

I usually download AndroidStudio and it comes with a GUI manager.
Here is some more [info](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update#sdk-manager) about how to update sdk tools.

You link it here: Edit/Preferences/External Tools
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but what I need is android build support, not android sdk. I think it is something connect unity and sdk, not sdk it self.

Comment: You need to build for android right?
My answer was not correct sorry.
The main requirement is JDK not the SDK.
See this: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html
But you setup both things essentially the same way. 
I think the package you download just does this in the background.
I build a couple of times for android and this does the job for me.
Also you will need this if you want to test with unity remote, which saves some time.
For unity remote you has to download "Usb Utilities" and something specific for your android phones's version. Dont remember what its name was.

Comment: You can also choose support options while installing unity from the unity hub

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me. To anyone facing this problem. I apologize for my long explanation and my english.

You can verify if *.pkg file is complete by comparing the checksum (I use [dolphin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEsLe.png))

Execute this command to manually install your `UnitySetup-Android-Support-for-Editor-*.pkg`

> :~> ./UnitySetup-2019.1.0f2 -u --use-component-list
>   unity-2019.1.0f2-linux.ini --install-location $HOME/2019.1.6f1/ -d
>   $HOME

**Note** that the unity version must be compatible, otherwise you will have the error unable to initialize the Unity engine in you android device. I use:

```
UnitySetup-Android-Support-for-Editor-2019.1.6f1
Unity-2019.1.6f1
```

As much as possible use [unity hub](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-hub-v2-0-0-release.677485/)  to install the android add-on, I use unity hub 2.0.1

**Step by step explanation of the installation manually of *.pkg**

**The problem :(**

I will put them in context.

I use opensuse tumbleweed. My problem was that I did not have android build support.
[No Android module loaded image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AHRZ.png), and when I press open download page, the browser shows me a message:

```
<Error> <Code>AccessDenied</Code> <Message>Access denied.</Message> <Details> Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to publishing-unity-binaries-prd/6e9a27477296/Unknown/UnitySetup-Android-Support-for-Editor-2018.3.0f2. </Details> </Error>
```

and I can not do anything else.

**The SOLUTION :)**

**0.- Previous requirements**

I already had my previous installation this file:

```
UnitySetup-2019.1.0f2
```

**1.- Download `UnitySetup-Android-Support-for-Editor-2019.1.x.pkg`**

To achieve this look for *UnitySetup-Android-Support-for-Editor-* in the file https://public-cdn.cloud.unity3d.com/hub/prod/releases-linux.json

This is a fragment of release-linux.json file

...
    {
      "id": "android",
      "name": "Android Build Support",
      "description": "Allows building your Unity projects for the Android platform",
      "downloadUrl": "h ttps://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/f2970305fe1c/MacEditorTargetInstaller/UnitySetup-Android-Support-for-Editor-2019.1.6f1.pkg",
      "category": "Platforms",
      "installedSize": 1958542000,
      "downloadSize": 664332318,
      "visible": true,
      "selected": false,
      "destination": "{UNITY_PATH}/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer",
      "checksum": "d00addecefb7babcb9cd6a8085672908"
    }
...

What interests us about this file is the url to download https://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/f2970305fe1c/MacEditorTargetInstaller/UnitySetup-Android-Support-for-Editor-2019.1.6f1.pkg and the checksum.

**2.- Component list file**

Download the file from the list of components from [here](https://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/dad990bf2728/unity-2018.2.7f1-linux.ini) or create a file like `unity-2019.1.0f2-linux.ini`:

```
[Android]
title=Android Build Support
description=Allows building your Unity projects for the Android platform
url=MacEditorTargetInstaller/UnitySetup-Android-Support-for-Editor-2019.1.6f1.pkg
md5=d00addecefb7babcb9cd6a8085672908
install=true
mandatory=false
size=365578263
installedsize=1259081000
requires_unity=false
```

for [Android] **install=true**, the url and md5 which is the checksum from the previous step (or again I get md5 with dolphin to verify)

**3.- Installation**

Have the following files in the same directory that in my case are in $HOME

```
UnitySetup-2019.1.0f2 
UnitySetup-Android-Support-for-Editor-2019.1.6f1.pkg
unity-2019.1.0f2-linux.ini
```

Finally, execute the following command line. (Note that my current unity installation is in $HOME/2019.1.6f1/).

```
:~> ./UnitySetup-2019.1.0f2 -u --use-component-list unity-2019.1.0f2-linux.ini --install-location $HOME/Unity-2019.1.6f1/ -d $HOME
```

Thanks

Source

https://forum.unity.com/threads/installing-android-build-support-and-other-build-support-post-installation.515436/

https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-install-editor-packages.554977/

Answer (score 1):

###### Add Unity modules on Linux manually:

1. Download pkg:

   Head to [this](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new) page, select your specific unity version from the dropdown at the right.
   For those modules that arent listed in linux section, download the pkg from the mac section.

2. Extract the pkg. you can use any of these:

   - Files
   - Archive Manager
   - `7z x -o* UnitySetup-XXXXXX-Support-for-Editor-2022.1.16f1.pkg`
   - `bsdtar -xf UnitySetup-XXXXXX-Support-for-Editor-2022.1.16f1.pkg TargetSupport.pkg.tmp/Payload`

3. Move the extracted "Payload" file to one of these directories:

   - For Android Build Support:

   > {UNITY_PATH}/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer

   - For Windows Build Support (Mono) & Windows Dedicated Server Build Support:

   > {UNITY_PATH}/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WindowsStandaloneSupport

   - For Mac Build Support (Mono) & Mac Dedicated Server Build Support:

   > {UNITY_PATH}/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/MacStandaloneSupport

4. Now decompress and extract Payload:

```
zcat Payload | cpio -iu && rm Payload
```

or if it's named Payload~ just extract it:

```
cpio -iu < Payload~ && rm Payload~
```

Comment: This works. Make sure to create AndroidPlayer dir in **PlaybackEngines** and not put the android build support in BuildTargetTools/AndroidPlayer which already exists

Answer (score 0):

According to [this:](https://forum.unity.com/threads/cannot-install-android-build-support.377877/)

> Possible causes could be:
>
> A corrupt package (download again manually from the list of individual
>   packages)
>
> Filesystem corruption (repair disk from single-user mode, reboot and
>   try again)
>
> The user account somehow not being in the sudoers group (deeper
>   technical problem - check Apple's forums)
>
> Package file stored on a drive formatted weirdly, so execute
>   permissions aren't set correctly (pre-/post-installation script won't
>   run; move to boot drive)

Comment: @Malloc No problem. If I helped you feel free to upvote or press the green tick next to my answer